# Can't get id from list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to pull out the value from the `id` attribute from a list item but the javascript runtime is throwing an error saying `attr is not supported`. What am I missing here?

Getting the first list item in the list then trying to get the `id` from it.

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var firstindex = $("li.imagethumbs").get(0);
        //console.log(firstindex);
        var id = firstindex.attr('id'); //error is thrown here
        $(ui.item).data("startindex", ui.item.index());
        // $(ui.item).data("firstindexid", id);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        self.sendUpdatedIndex(ui.item);
    }
});
```

Comment: `.get(0)` returns the first underlying Javascript object. The `.attr()` method can only be used on jQuery objects.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because `get(0)` returns a DOMElement, not a jQuery object, and DOMElements do not have the `attr()` method.

Instead you can access the `id` property of the DOMElement:

```
var item = $("li.imagethumbs").get(0);
var id = item.id;
```

Or to use jQuery, if you want to retrieve the first element in a set use `first()`;

```
var $firstLi = $("li.imagethumbs").first();
var id = $firstLi.attr('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this : wrap fistindex in jQuery because `$("li.imagethumbs").get(0);` will return javascript object and you need jQuery object to call `attr()` method

```
var id = $(firstindex).attr('id');
```

Or

```
    var $firstindex = $("li.imagethumbs:first");
    var id = $firstindex.attr('id');
```